# Find image-url specified in css content from Capybara

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capybara

I have specified the `image-url` in `css` file rather than in `img` tag in `html`. That is because I have one layout for many stylesheets in my Rails application. Now I am not able to find that image from Capybara. How can I do that?

**html**

```
<div id="company_logos">
  <div id="first_logo"></div>
  <div id="second_logo"></div>
</div>
```

**css**

```
#company_logos {
  /* css for parent  */
}

#first_logo {
  content: image-url(company_name/company_logo.png);
}

#second_logo {
  display: none;
}
```

**capybara_test.rb**

```
within('#company_logos') do
  within('#first_logo') do
    assert find('content')['src'].include? "company_name/first_logo"
  end
end
```

I am getting the error: `unable to find content`. How can I rectify this so that `capybara` finds the `content image-url`?

Comment: I'm rusty with capybara, but if you're expecting an image, won't there be an image tag that you can find and check the src of in your test?

Answer (score 0):

In your test you're trying to check the elements style. One way to do that is via the `style` filter which can be used with any element finder/matcher/assertion in Capybara

```
assert_selector(:css, '#first_logo', style: { content: /company_name\/first_logo/ })
```

If you've already found the element you want to verify the style on (`element`) then you can use `assert_matches_style`

```
assert_matches_style(element, content: /company_name\/first_logo/) # assuming you're using minitest
```

Note: this all assumes you're using a driver which processes CSS (ie NOT the rack_test driver)